# Random Forest in R getting classification rules/centers

Tags: r, clustering, random-forest

Is it possible for a supervised random forest to obtain the cluster centers like in kmeans? I mean, if I train the Rf, I want the characteristics for every cluster ie. the mean values for every feature specifing each cluster.

E.G: I use a random forest to rtain which features are important (and what mean values they have) to buy a specific product (the class lables)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you put a classifier in this process? It can only increase the error.

Just compute the centers of each class in your training data.